# sessionStorage on form submit

Tags: javascript, dom

I am creating a form and the `onsubmit` attribute has a form validation boolean method. At the end of the method, it does not matter whether or not none of the invalid inputs have returned `false`, the `sessionStorage` variable is to be updated to `true` so that upon loading the page again the variable will be rechecked. Why is the variable still `false` whether none of the inputs returned `false` or not? Keep in mind that the form `action` attribute leads to the same page (form page). This is how my validation looks like:

```html
<form action="form.jsp" onsubmit="return validate()">
   <input type="text" id="foo" />
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById("foo"); // textbox
function validate()
{
   if (input.value.trim() === "") {
      return false;
   }
   sessionStorage.setItem("submitted","true");
}
```

Keep in mind that all form inputs exist and the sessionStorage variable is not updated even after the function doesn't return `false`.

Comment: Assuming you have `<input type="text" id="foo" />` someplace?

Comment: `return false` ends the function before you set session storage. Set the session storage first.

Comment: @Barmar what if the function doesn't return false? The sessionStorage is still not updated.

Comment: @Shanimal yes the form inputs are existent

Comment: Can you recreate this problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/ 
I wonder if you have something else going on.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Your code does set the value, provided the input field was not empty.

Comment: @SerjSagan https://jsfiddle.net/y36vfrbx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your `jsfiddle` code, the reason is because you are checking its value like this:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("submitted") == true)
```

This is not accurate as the data stored there is a string... so to fix this you can do:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("submitted") == 'true')
```

You actually **can't** even check it like this:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("submitted"))
```

Because that will return `true` for any non-null value, even `'false'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the sessionStorage call in a try/catch to see why it's failing.

```js
function validate() {
  var input = document.getElementById("foo"); // textbox
  console.log('validate', input);
  if (input.value.trim() === "") {
    return false;
  }
  try {
    sessionStorage.setItem("submitted", "true");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return false;
  }

  // (for demostration purposes return false)
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input type="text" id="foo" />
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```

Alternatively you can use the "Preserve log" checkbox in DevTools to retain the console errors.